# How to escape dot (.) in a key to get JSON value with redis-py?

Tags: python, json, redis

I had some JSON data containing dot(.) in keys that are written to redis using redis-py like this:

```py
r = redis.Redis()
r.json().set(_id, "$", {'First.Last': "John.Smith"})
```

It works if reading the whole JSON data like

```py
r.json().get(_id)
```

but error throws if directly getting the value with a path containing the dot:

```
r.json().get(_id, "First\.Last")  # ResponseError
```

Obviously, the dot is not correctly escaped. Also tried to quote it like `"'First.Last'"`but doesn't work either. What's the correct way to deal with this special character in a key? The redis instance is a redis-stack-server docker container running on linux. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RedisJSON path supports both dot and bracket notation https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/path/, so you could use this

```
r.json().get(_id, '["First.Last"]')
```